# Converting a dtype: object to datetime not converting

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert the df['start_time_time'] column from object to datetime.

| start_time | start_time_time |
| --- | --- |
| 2019-01-01 00:04:37 | 00:04:37 |
| 2019-01-01 00:14:52 | 00:14:52 |

The df['start_time_time'] column was extracted from the df['start_time'] column.

I tried converting using this:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['start_time_time'], format='%H:%M:%S').dt.time
```

But the data type is still shown as an object.

I also tried this:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['start_time_time'], format='%H:%M:%S')
```

Which successfully converts it to datetime64, but the results include the (wrong) date as seen below:

| start_time | start_time_time |
| --- | --- |
| 2019-01-01 00:04:37 | 1900-01-01 00:04:37 |
| 2019-01-01 00:14:52 | 1900-01-01 00:14:52 |

Does the datetime format have to include a date?

I am looking for a way to organize/sort the rows by time regardless of date.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
df['start_time_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_time_time']).dt.normalize()
```

It will convert your date to `'datetime64'` datatype